# "not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

I am having problems figuring out how to solve the following error when trying to combine two queries:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Column 'dbo.tbl_Person.perMailingLabel' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help in understanding why this is happening and a solution would be greatly appreciated!

```
WITH AgeData AS
(
SELECT p.perMailingLabel,
         p.perDOB,
         DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.perDOB, GETDATE()) AS [AGE], 
         sr.strRegion AS 'State Region', 
         COUNT (*) AS 'State Region Total'
FROM dbo.fnAllEmails(1) AS e
INNER JOIN tbl_Subscription AS s
    ON s.subsubscription_ID = e.MembershipId
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Person AS P
    ON s.perPerson_ID = p.perPerson_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Address AS a
    ON s.perPerson_ID = a.perPerson_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.val_StateRegion AS sr
    ON sr.strState_ID = a.strState_ID
WHERE s.subsubscription_ID
IN (000001, 
000007, 
000016, 
000150, 
000287, 
000305, 
000337, 
000535, 
000541, 
000651 
)
AND a.addPrimaryAdd = 1),

GroupAge AS
(
  SELECT p.perMailingLabel,
         p.perDOB,
         Age,
         CASE
             WHEN AGE < 30 THEN 'Under 30'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31 - 40'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41 - 50'
             WHEN AGE > 50 THEN 'Over 50'
             ELSE 'Invalid Birthdate'
         END AS [Age Groups]
  FROM AgeData
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [AgeGrpCount],
       [Age Groups]
FROM GroupAge
GROUP BY [Age Groups]
ORDER BY AgeGrpCount DESC;
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The first CTE has no `GROUP BY` so it can't use any aggregate functions like `COUNT(*)`. What do you expect `COUNT(*)` to return in that case?

Comment: Which part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Before writing complex query, you should learn how to use aggregate functions.  Please start with simple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to your question, you're missing a `group by` clause to correspond with your `count(*)` in the `AgeData` CTE.  If you still don't understand why this is required, just read up further onit.

If you do see the issue and it was a goof that you just couldn't see, then the deeper issue causing you to miss it may be your code organization.  I made the following changes to your code that may help you catch things like this in the future:

- I added a `group by` clause in the AgeData CTE with the relevant columns.
- I moved your calculation of 'Age' into a cross apply statement of the first CTE.  This allows elimination of the second CTE entirely.  I then pointed your base query to the first CTE.
- Case statements operate in sequential order, so the 'between' approach can be converted to a simple '<=' approach.  This is very optional and you may find 'between' more readable.  However, unless an age of 30 is an invalid birth date, you'll want to reform your logic to account for it.  I did in my revision.
- Your `in` statement has numbers with leading 0's in them.  I imagine in this case the values are really stored as strings.  So I converted your numbers to strings to make this clear.
- You mix quoted identifiers with bracketed identifiers.  I chose one for consistency.  I also changed from `value as fieldName` to `fieldName = value`, but this is just preference.  I just like to see the fieldNames first.  But not all SQL dialects allow this.
- I changed your `inner join` statements to simple `join` statements.  Again, just a matter of preference but just demonstrating that it's the same thing.

Of course, the code is untested, so it may have something off here or there, but you get the idea.  And it would be much easier to catch some of the issues identified with this or some other better organized structure.  Here's the code:

```
with AgeData as (

    select      p.perMailingLabel,
                p.perDOB,
                ap.AGE, 

                [Age Groups] = 
                    case
                    when age <= 30 then '30 or under'
                    when age <= 40 then '31 - 40'
                    when age <= 50 then '41 - 50'
                    when age > 50 then 'Over 50'
                    else 'Invalid Birthdate'
                    end,

                [State Region] = sr.strRegion, 
                [State Region Total] = count(*)

    from        dbo.fnAllEmails(1) e
    join        tbl_Subscription s on s.subsubscription_ID = e.MembershipId
    join        tbl_Person p on s.perPerson_ID = p.perPerson_ID
    join        tbl_Address a on s.perPerson_ID = a.perPerson_ID
    join        val_StateRegion sr on sr.strState_ID = a.strState_ID
    cross apply (select age = datediff(year, p.perDOB, getdate())) ap
    where       a.addPrimaryAdd = 1
    and         s.subsubscription_ID in (
                    '000001', '000007', '000016', '000150', '000287', 
                    '000305', '000337', '000535', '000541', '000651'
                )
    group by    p.perMailingLabel,
                p.perDOB,
                ap.AGE, 
                sr.strRegion 

)

select      AgeGrpCount = count(*),
            [Age Groups]
from        ageData
group by    [Age Groups]
order by    AgeGrpCount desc;
```

Comment: Thank you @pwilcox for taking the time to break down the information! I will give the code a test here in a bit.  After years of Access, I have to relearn everything using SQL!

Comment: it ran perfectly without errors. I can modify it from here to get what I am looking for. Thank you again!